# Cases where text is not displayed at full screen in UnityRoom

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]https://unityroom.com/games/akasatanahamayarawa

The minesweeper screen in the game linked here disappears text when in fullscreen. At the moment of changing to full screen on that screen, the text is displayed in a slightly blurry state, but when clicking on the screen, the text disappears.

I would like to know the cause and how to deal with this problem.

Also, we found this bug when we checked on a smartphone, and when we checked fullscreen on a desktop, it was the same.

Additionally, I changed the font and it is now displayed. I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem because it is inconvenient if I cannot use the fonts I want to use in the future.

Comment: Sounds like your text is not scaling with the screen correctly but i did not see what you mean on your game - perhaps a picture or 2 would have been better

Comment: doesn't reproduce for me .. text is there on your main link, when going to full screen .. and also when opening in a new tab .. as well as in fullscreen there  ...